# (Typescript) How to push variable into array and keep its value always updated?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a structure like this:

```
export var CustomDropdown: any[] = [
    { 
        class_name: "fonts-list", 
        list: false,
        ...
    }
]
```

After initializing this variable, I create another one:

```
CustomDropdown.push(
    { 
        class_name: "colors-list", 
        list: CustomDropdown[0].list,
        ...
    }
)
```

You see, the second time I instance this structure, I refer `list` from the first one. That's working fine.

The thing is, I want the `list` key to always maintain itself updated with the first one (if the first one's `list` becomes true, the second's one should also).

The thing is, that does not happen, and I believe it's because, when the second element is made, it just reads the `list` value of the first, but it does not create any connection between them.

So I believe something like a C pointer would fix my problem, or any other strategy that I do no know.

Also, I **do not** want a function to control this, only if its impossible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list` will be end up being an Array as the name implies (that you initialized with false), you could do this instead:

```
export var CustomDropdown: any[] = [
    { 
        class_name: "fonts-list", 
        list: [],                  // empty Array (1)
        ...
    }
]

CustomDropdown.push(
    { 
        class_name: "colors-list", 
        list: CustomDropdown[0].list, // "reference" sharing of (1)
        ...
    }
);
```

From here, if you do `CustomDropdown[i].list.push(element)`, this will be reflected in `CustomDropdown[0].list`.

Other than that, you can't really pass the value of a primitive such as boolean by sharing ("reference") I believe.

Comment: I believe the problem with this is that my 'list' value will become true by the use of a checkbox, and Angular's automatic ngModel (I want this one checkbox to affect every instance of this object). So a `CustomDropdown[i].list.push(element)` never happens